# Error while doing cordova build

Tags: android, cordova, android-build

I'm trying to take android build using cordova.
I have installed cordova.

[image]

Added android platform
[image]

Now when, I run cordova build I'm getting below error

[image]

Where as, My android home is set correctly in PATH, 
(variable ANDROID_HOME = C:\Program Files\Android\sdk;
 and in PATH : %ANDROID_HOME%\tools; %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;)

Also, If you see my sdk manager it shows android 23 installed

[image]

In **\platforms\android\project.properties** and **\platforms\android\CordovaLib\project.properties**  target=android-23 is there.
I modified AndroidManifest.xml to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />`

But still no luck. Please help!!

Comment: You should install all packages from  Android 6.0(API 23)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of the SDK manager shows that you've got the

- SDK Tools
- Platform-tools
- Build-tools

but NOT the API version 23 (checkmarks shown at the bottom of the image).

Re-open the SDK manager, Make sure the checkboxes for API 23 are checked and hit "Intstall packages"

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.